# Prediction intervals for negative binomial regression (R)

Tags: r, prediction

I'm trying to estimate *prediction* intervals (not confidence intervals) from a negative binomial regression model.

I understand that I can't simply use `predict()`, as `predict.glm()`, unlike `predict.lm()`, doesn't let you specify `interval = "prediction"` - so it would return a confidence interval around a mean, rather than a prediction interval.

```r
head(cars)
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
#> 2     4   10
#> 3     7    4
#> 4     7   22
#> 5     8   16
#> 6     9   10
```

I've seen that you can use `ciTools::add_pi()` for this purpose. This works fine in the basic scenario:

```r
fit <- cars |>
    MASS::glm.nb(dist ~ speed, data = _)

cars |>
    ciTools::add_pi(fit) |>
    head()
#>   speed dist     pred LPB0.025 UPB0.975
#> 1     4    2 11.42897        3       23
#> 2     4   10 11.42897        3       24
#> 3     7    4 15.63866        5       30
#> 4     7   22 15.63866        5       31
#> 5     8   16 17.36189        6       34
#> 6     9   10 19.27501        7       37
```

However, I'd like the predictions also for a new set of data (e.g. `speed= c(58, 63, 121)`). When I try doing this, I get a length mismatch error. This wouldn't happen if I used `predict()` on a linear model.

```r
cars |>
    tibble::add_row(speed = c(58, 63, 121)) |>
    ciTools::add_pi(fit)
#> Warning in mu * rgamma(k, theta): longer object length is not a multiple of
#> shorter object length
#> Error in rpois(k, (mu * rgamma(k, theta))/theta): dims [product 50] do not match the length of object [53]
```

Any thoughts?

(EDIT: I originally mistakingly wrote "dist" when I meant "speed" when creating a new set of data - thanks Dave for pointing it out in the answer).

Answer (score 3):

The function that generates the confidence intervals uses the provided data to create the model matrix which list wise deletes the input data - removing the hypothetical rows from the predictions.

You can find the "guts" of the function that actually does the work and bend that function to your own needs.  When you call `add_pi()`, it calls `add_pi.negbin()`, which, in turn, calls `sim_pi_negbin()`, which calls the function `get_sim_response_nb()` which does the heavy lifting.  This argument takes the data, model object and number of simulations (as `nSims`).  This is what `ciTools:::get_sim_response_nb()` looks like:

```r
function (df, fit, nSims) 
{
    nPreds <- NROW(df)
    modmat <- model.matrix(fit, data = df)
    response_distr <- fit$family$family
    inverselink <- fit$family$linkinv
    sims <- get_negbin_sims(fit, nSims)
    sim_response <- matrix(0, ncol = nSims, nrow = nPreds)
    for (i in 1:nSims) {
        yhat <- inverselink(modmat %*% sims@coef[i, ])
        sim_response[, i] <- rnegbin(n = nPreds, mu = yhat, theta = fit$theta)
    }
    sim_response
}
```

The important thing when trying to use this function is that you need to be able to provide the model matrix rather than using the one that gets automatically calculated. You could then change the `df` argument so it expects the model matrix. You may also want the function not make the prediction intervals.  You could add an `alpha` argument to identify the level at which you want to make the interval.

```r
fit <- cars |>
  MASS::glm.nb(dist ~ speed, data = _)

my_sim_response_nb <- function (modmat, fit, nSims, alpha=.05) 
{
  nPreds <- nrow(modmat)
  response_distr <- fit$family$family
  inverselink <- fit$family$linkinv
  sims <- ciTools:::get_negbin_sims(fit, nSims)
  sim_response <- matrix(0, ncol = nSims, nrow = nPreds)
  for (i in 1:nSims) {
    yhat <- inverselink(modmat %*% sims@coef[i, ])
    sim_response[, i] <- MASS::rnegbin(n = nPreds, mu = yhat, theta = fit$theta)
  }
  t(round(apply(sim_response, 1, function(x)quantile(x, probs=c(alpha/2, 1-alpha/2)))))
}
```

Then, you just call the function with the appropriate model matrix and the result on the other end is your desired prediction interval.

```r
set.seed(519)
newdat <- data.frame(speed = c(12,15,19))
my_sim_response_nb(modmat = cbind(1, newdat$speed), 
                   fit = fit, 
                   nSims = 2500, 
                   alpha = .05)
#>      2.5% 97.5%
#> [1,]   10    50
#> [2,]   14    68
#> [3,]   23   101
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for a detailed and helpful answer. Yes, I got confused, I meant to write `speed` as new data, edited now. I'll digest your code and explanation and see if it solves my wider problem. I'm honestly surprised that there doesn't seem to be an easier way of doing this with MASS.

Comment: prediction intervals for GLMs are not very commonly used IME (they're tricky/require simulation as in this implementation because of the non-Gaussian response)